How to model a polynomial function with many features and multiple outputs
With linear regression (and multiple linear regression), one can have many features but only one output as y. I need to build a model with multiple x's that also outputs multiple y's in a polynomial fit. What i'm trying to do is to estimate the trajectory of a ball over x seconds thrown by a person using features such as weight, height, arm length, baseball experience in years. So the explanatory variables will be as x's weight, height, arm length, experience, and the different y's will be altitude after throw at 0.5seconds, 1seconds, 2 seconds, 3seconds, 4 seconds. As one can imagine, maybe the larger the weight, and larger the height, and more years of experience would yield a different output in those 5 y's versus someone not. So ideally the function would take those inputs and output the 0.5seconds, 1seconds, 2 seconds, 3seconds, 4 seconds.
also wondering if just doing 5 separate multiple linear regressions would be ok for the 5 different time outputs...?

As stated, your problem setup is looking for five different polynomials to fit to the data, one for  each elapsed time delay.
However, using domain knowledge from physics, it suffices to learn the angle and initial velocity of the ball. That determines the parabola of its trajectory, which we can examine at any elapsed time prior to contact with the ballfield. This assumes that several things are held constant: the altitude of release, the ball’s mass, its diameter, its surface roughness, local acceleration of gravity, and air density.

Hi J_H, thanks for the reply. The above is just an example for the problem of this type in general where it takes multiple inputs to estimate outputs that also has different outputs

In general if you want to output a vector of N continuous target variables, you'll want to fit N regressions to the input data. When the next question comes up, rather than follow the X Y format it would be best to cut to the chase, to the Y part.

hey J_H thx for the additional color. I was thinking that because the target output is most likely a polynomial function given the nature of the curvature in my problem statement that it might be possible to regress x variables that output the entire set of ys as one unit instead of the 5 time intervals separately. Is this possible?
